# Fulltext: How to get the searched words when using Thesaurus?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, highlighting

I am using Sql Server 2008 R2. I have a table with a fulltext column. My queries are like

```
select fieldlist from table
where contains(field, 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "word")');
```

I need to know what are the words that SQL used to search, because it uses my custom thesaurus list. I know I can query sql server to get the words used by doing:

```
SELECT display_term as term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "word")', 1046, 5, 0)
```

But I need to know for every row returned what were the words searched, so I created this query:

```
select fieldlist (

SELECT display_term as term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "word")', 1046, 5, 0)
as f
for xml Auto, root ('items')

) as teste
from table
where contains(field, 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "word")');
```

My question is: is this the right way of accomplish what I need? I am doing that because I need to highlight the searched terms.

Comment: Does it return the info you need, and you're just curious if another way is better... or does this way not work, and you're looking for a way that will?

Comment: It does return the info I need and i am curious if another way is better.